# Unable to use then on ios swift promisekit

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I created a promise which gets some data from API and returns it. Now what i am stuck is after getting the json data i need to store them on device storage (realm). After calling the promise when i try with then i get some error stating Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Void' to expected argument type '(_) -> _' . But when i try with done it works perfectly. But i need to use then to save the data on realm.

Following approch works fine

```
Translator().translators().done { data -> Void in
            print(data[0].name)
            }.catch { error in
                print(error)
        }
```

But following two approach fails

```
Translator().translators().then() { data -> Void in
            print(data)
            }.catch() {
                (e: Error) in
                print(e)
        }
```

Above gives an error that says

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Void' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'
```

and following approach gives another similar error

```
Translator().translators().then() {
            (data: [Translator]) -> Void in
            print(data[0].name)
            }.catch() {
                (e: Error) in
                print(e)
        }
```

error message:

```
Cannot convert value of type '([Translator]) -> Void' to expected argument type '([Translator]) -> _'
```

Promise i created:

```
func translators() -> Promise<[Translator]> {
        return firstly {
            Alamofire.request("http://192.168.0.107:3000/translatdors", method: .get).responseData()
            }.map {
                try JSONDecoder().decode([Translator].self, from: $0.data)
        }
    }
```

Image of my code and error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return a `promise` when you do `.then` because until `.done` you are not finished. I don't see any issue in saving realm data in `.done` as your method has no return type.

Incase you still want to use `.then`, it can be done this way.

```
Translator().translators().then({ data -> Promise<[Translator]> in
            return Promise.value(data)
            }).done({ data in
            // Save to realm
           }).catch({ error in
              print(error.localizedDescription)
           })
```

Comment: I am actually playing with promisekit. Now I understand the issue. got misdirected by the error message. thanks brother.